# Which version of MySQL should I install on 32-bit RHEL 5?

Tags: linux, mysql, redhat, rhel5

```
$ uname -a
Linux host.domain.com 2.6.18-128.1.1.el5 #1 SMP Mon Jan 26 13:59:00 
    EST 2009 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

I would like to install MySQL under `/usr/local` and not use the RPM installer. The [download page](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.0.html#linux) offers...

Linux (x86, glibc-2.2, "standard" is static)

and

Linux (x86)

Which is the right one? Going by the docs it seems like I want the first one because it says "the binary release is linked with -static, which means you do not normally need to worry about which version of the system libraries you have", but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have a good reason to avoid the packaged version? If there's any chance of this system having some security exposure, are you going to keep up on the latest versions?

Comment: Yep, you should definatly run the rhel version unless you have a good reason not to. If nothing else, the version packaged has been tested against the other software versions you're running, where as the version from mysql.com has not. As well as that, using the rhel package insures that you'll get your install updated against any security or other important bugs that arise.

Answer (score 1):

You should install the packaged version that RedHat provides as part of RHEL5.

If there's a good reason not to, you should spell it out, because it might affect the question of which other ways to install it there are.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the statically linked version. When using the dynamic version I've run into compatibility issues later on. I also prefer to install from the source.